# htaccess ignore specific directory in URI - treat same as root

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

been looking for several hours now without success.
I'd like all urls containing `/en/` to ignore this part but continue with all other rules in the htaccess (like php to no extension rule).

**EXAMPLE**
`www.domain.com/en/gallery` -> should point to `gallery.php` in my server root
`www.domain.com/gallery` -> should ALSO point to `gallery.php` in my server root
(will have to take care of duplicate content here somehow later)
`www.domain.com/en/contact` -> should point to `contact.php` in my root

Thank you

**U P D A T E**
Like mentioned in my question I'd like all other rules to still be running.
Only  this rule does not work with below solution as it should work with
`www.domain.com/en/category1` AND `www.domain.com/category1` so with or without EN.
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp|\.css|\.js|\.ico)$

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? /categories.php?rw=1&url=$1 [L,QSA]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(?:en/)?([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

**UPDATE:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(png|jpe?g|gif|bmp|css|js|ico)$
RewriteRule ^(?:en/)?([^/]+)/?$ categories.php?rw=1&url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you works! Only one rule isn't functional anymore - please see above!

Comment: Thank you. With updated rule www.domain.com/en/category1 is ok but www.domain.com/category1 will give a 404.